# How to share a photo correctly on php and URL solution - Webproject

Tags: php, html, web, share

I have a question about a web project I'm on it.

The situation:
There is a log-in system -> after log-in there is a lot of photos.

1) I enter with my credentials -> login.php to index.php

2) I see my profile and then I want to share it with twitter(for example..).

3) The thing I share it is the URL which is "page.com/index.php#&album=1&id=1"

The problem is the URL, if I share will be useless because if the other user have an account, will show his photo and not mine.

I try to find a solution, I do not know how the other sites do to share photos without this problem.

Hope u can help me and sorry if my english not the best.

Comment: read about `twitter cards`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do this by generating a [UUID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier) for each individual photo stored alongside the photos, and using that in the URL instead of the two IDs, so your URLs would look something like:

```
http://example.com/photos/123e4567-e89b-12d3-a456-426655440000
```

You can then share this URL to anyone, and add the logic in to the server to decide whether or not the photo should be visible to whoever is requesting it.

If you want a more memorable or easy to type UUID, there are lots of libraries that will create them for you in different formats.

The main benefit of this is simplicity, you just have that one UUID for that one photo, and it doesn't matter how your design changes (for example, if you remove albums), you have a very good chance of being able to keep the URLs the same, or at least, to continue supporting the original URL if you do need to change the format on the future.

Another big benefit is that whatever you use as a UUID will (should) be hard to guess, so you remove a potential route in for an attacker, who otherwise might be able to iterate over IDs, and have confidence that he's created a genuine URL.

Answer (score -1):

You need make one more route for sharing pictures.

```
/share.php?user=1&album=1&id=1
```

In this file you get all parameters (user, album, id) to show correct photo.

And you need to add this route to share in index.php.

Facebook example: `https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=http%3A//site.com/share.php?user=1%26album=1%26id=1`

Comment: The risk with this is that, if the `user` ID is constant for that user, you've added a potential security vulnerability, because if you share a photo with me, I can potentially try just trying different values for the `album` and `id` and harvest all your photos. Obviously you'll have some checks on the server to verify whether or not I have permission to access those photos, but if there's any small hole in that security, I have an additional chance to get through, that wouldn't be available to me if make your URLs independent of the actual IDs of photos, albums or users.

Comment: I guess question is in "how to show correct photo?". Security is an important thing but it's another thing